# How should I connect a GFCI outlet on a well pump circuit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I need help installing a GFI that's outside house. In the box there are 2 white wires and 2 black & bare ground. One set of wires come from the house and the other 2 go to a well. I tried hooking the white from the house to the Line silver and black to brass Line then the 2 well wires to the Load side. White to silver and black to Brass. When I do this the outlet is dead and well pump.

Then I connected both the white wires to only 1 silver screw on line side and both black to 1 brass screw to line side. I got power at GFI now and the well pump is working but using a Stat SP-101 - Electrical Ground Checker it is showing all 3 lights lit up. I think there is a problem? or is there. Thanks Troy

Comment: Do you intend for the well pump to be GFI protected, or just the outlet?

Comment: The well pump probably has a ground fault.  People tend to always blame the protection device for doing its job correctly.

Comment: **Are you SURE this is a 120V circuit and not 240?**  What was in the junction box before you added the GFCI? Do any white wires have tape on them? Reading your words literally, you did not attach ground to the GFCI which would also do this,  but I bet it's 240.

Comment: Ok at the well pump it goes to an on/off switch for the pump and not an outlet. I just purchased the house and they had a regular outlet, no GFI and it was not working. They had the 2 white going to one screw and the black going to the other. I used a volt meter to test the old outlet and showed no voltage. When I took it out the wires tested hot so I tried to put in the GFI. I think Harper might be correct. They made that 110 to a 220 but why did they leave it connected to a 110 outlet but showed no voltage? The outlet should have showed 220 with my meter? PS: I did have the ground connected.

Comment: no tape on the wires

Comment: How many spaces does the breaker for the well pump circuit take up, and what size breaker is it?